# Can't retrieve full URL of external webpage with curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am using curl and regex to scrape specific URLs from a page so that I may then parse those child pages. However the URLs I retrieve from the master page change after the links are followed.

E.G. I retrieve the following URLs from the master page:

```
https://www.crowdcube.com/investment/labrador-ltd-22191   
https://www.crowdcube.com/investment/wegow-21995
```

When I open these links the URLs change to these in the browser:

```
https://www.crowdcube.com/companies/labrador-ltd/pitches/qayzEq   
https://www.crowdcube.com/companies/wegow/pitches/qY9EXq
```

This results in me being unable to use the original URLs with my curl script.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried using curl with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?

Comment: Those pages are responding with a 302, properly handle the 302 and follow it...

Comment: @JacobRiches np. I copied the solution to your question to an answer. Please confirm it, so that this question can be completed and other may also find this solution. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option, so it will follow any redirect automatically.